# How to use ACR35 NFC Reader in Android

Tags: android, nfc

I'm new in developing with ACR or NFC Reader, especially for Android. And recently I need to use an ACR35 and I've got the SDK and the example from [this acs official website](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/341/acr35-nfc-mobilemate-card-reader/). And It works just fine as an example.
And now I need to create an activity that will always be ready to check whether nfc card is tapped. But the problem is I don't know how to detect when the nfc card is tapped and I don't know what to do next, and I can't find the way out from the example as it detects nfc card when I touch the 'transmit' button, it doesn't do it automatically.
Please give me with example code.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but it might help someone.
I have found following project on the git hub. It shows how to read tag id from the acr35 
[here](https://github.com/stuart-xyz/acr35)
.

I have been using acr35 for some time to read the tag id. From my experience is a buggy device on Android. I tested around 10 devices and it worked only on 3...

I read from it every second. It returns results from the last card even though it is not present there anymore. Therefore; I have to reset it twice per every successful read and it takes around 6 seconds to get the device in reading state again... Also be very careful with multithreading.

My implementation based on mentioned project - added simple locking to stop querying the card after successfull reading + full device reset, filternig same uuid which was read in very short time after it was read previously:

ACR3x class

```
import com.acs.audiojack.AudioJackReader;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import sk.tido.util.ByteHex;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * This class allows control of the ACR35 reader sleep state and PICC commands
 */
public class Acr3x {

    private Acr3xTransmitter transmitter;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private AudioJackReader mReader;

    private boolean firstReset = true;  /** Is this the first reset of the reader? */

    /** APDU command for reading a card's UID */
    private final byte[] apdu = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };
    /** Timeout for APDU response (in <b>seconds</b>) */
    private final int timeout = 1;
    private int acr3xCardType = AudioJackReader.PICC_CARD_TYPE_ISO14443_TYPE_A
            | AudioJackReader.PICC_CARD_TYPE_ISO14443_TYPE_B
            | AudioJackReader.PICC_CARD_TYPE_FELICA_212KBPS
            | AudioJackReader.PICC_CARD_TYPE_FELICA_424KBPS
            | AudioJackReader.PICC_CARD_TYPE_AUTO_RATS;

    private int acr3xStartAudioLevel = 0;

    private Object locking = new Object();

    private String lastUuid = "";
    private Date lastUuidDate = new Date();


    public Acr3x(AudioManager mAudioManager){
        this.mAudioManager = mAudioManager;
    }

    public void start(final Acr3xNotifListener listener){
        Runnable r = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mReader == null){
                    mReader = new AudioJackReader(mAudioManager);
                }
                System.out.println("ACR35 reader start");

                acr3xStartAudioLevel = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                System.out.println("acr3x start audio stream level: " + acr3xStartAudioLevel);
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
                System.out.println("acr3x set audio stream level: " + mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

                mReader.start();
                mReader.setSleepTimeout(30);
                mReader.setOnFirmwareVersionAvailableListener(new AudioJackReader.OnFirmwareVersionAvailableListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFirmwareVersionAvailable(AudioJackReader reader,
                        String firmwareVersion) {
                        System.out.println("acr3x firmware version: " + firmwareVersion);
                        if(listener != null){
                            listener.onFirmwareVersionAvailable(firmwareVersion);
                        }
                        Acr3x.this.read(listener);

                    }
                });
                mReader.reset(new AudioJackReader.OnResetCompleteListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onResetComplete(AudioJackReader arg0) {
                        mReader.getFirmwareVersion();

                    }

                });
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(r, "Acr3xInitThread");
        t.start();

    }


    /**
     * Sets the ACR35 reader to continuously poll for the presence of a card. If a card is found,
     * the UID will be returned to the Apache Cordova application
     *
     * @param callbackContext: the callback context provided by Cordova
     * @param cardType: the integer representing card type
     */
    public void read(final Acr3xNotifListener callbackContext){
        System.out.println("acr3x setting up for reading...");
        firstReset = true;

        /* Set the PICC response APDU callback */
        mReader.setOnPiccResponseApduAvailableListener
                (new AudioJackReader.OnPiccResponseApduAvailableListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPiccResponseApduAvailable(AudioJackReader reader,
                                                            byte[] responseApdu) {
                        /* Update the connection status of the transmitter */
                        transmitter.updateStatus(true);

                        /* Print out the UID */
                        String uuid = ByteHex.bytesToHex(responseApdu);

                        if(uuid.equalsIgnoreCase("0x9000")){
                            return;
                        }

                        if(uuid.endsWith("9000")){
                            uuid = uuid.substring(0, uuid.length() - 4);
                        }

                        if(uuid.equals(lastUuid)){ // na odfiltrovanie opakujucich sa uuid z citacky z predchadzajuceho citania
                            if(new Date().getTime() - lastUuidDate.getTime() < 3000){
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        lastUuid = uuid;
                        lastUuidDate = new Date();

                        synchronized(locking){

                            System.out.println("acr3x uuid: " + uuid);

                            if(callbackContext != null){
                                callbackContext.onUUIDAavailable(uuid);
                            }
                            System.out.println("acr3x restarting reader");
                            transmitter.kill();
                            try {
                                locking.wait(2000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        read(callbackContext);



                    }
                });

        /* Set the reset complete callback */
        mReader.setOnResetCompleteListener(new AudioJackReader.OnResetCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResetComplete(AudioJackReader reader) {
                System.out.println("acr3x reset complete");

                /* If this is the first reset, the ACR35 reader must be turned off and back on again
                   to work reliably... */
                Thread t = null;
                if(firstReset){  //firstReset
                    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try{
                                /* Set the reader asleep */
                                mReader.sleep();
                                /* Wait one second */
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                                /* Reset the reader */
                                mReader.reset();

                                firstReset = false;
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                // TODO: add exception handling
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    /* Create a new transmitter for the UID read command */
                    transmitter = new Acr3xTransmitter(mReader, mAudioManager, timeout,
                            apdu, acr3xCardType, locking);
                    t = new Thread(transmitter);
                }
                t.start();
            }
        });

        mReader.start();
        mReader.reset();
        System.out.println("acr3x setup complete");
    }

    public void stop(){
        if(transmitter != null){
            transmitter.kill();
        }

        System.out.println("acr3x restoring audio level: " + acr3xStartAudioLevel);
        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,acr3xStartAudioLevel, 0);
        System.out.println("acr3x set audio stream level: " + mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

        if(mReader != null){
            mReader.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Transmitter class

```
    import com.acs.audiojack.AudioJackReader;

import android.media.AudioManager;

/**
 * This class sets up an independent thread for card polling, and is linked to the
 * <code>setOnPiccResponseApduAvailableListener</code> callback function
 */

public class Acr3xTransmitter implements Runnable {

    private AudioJackReader mReader;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    //private CallbackContext mContext;

    private boolean killMe = false;          /** Stop the polling thread? */
    private int itersWithoutResponse = 0;    /** The number of iterations that have passed with no
                                                 response from the reader */
    private boolean readerConnected = true;  /** Is the reader currently connected? */

    private int cardType;
    private int timeout;
    private byte[] apdu;
    private Object locking;

    /**
     * @param mReader: AudioJack reader service
     * @param mAudioManager: system audio service
     * @param mContext: context for plugin results
     * @param timeout: time in <b>seconds</b> to wait for commands to complete
     * @param apdu: byte array containing the command to be sent
     * @param cardType: the integer representing card type
     */
    public Acr3xTransmitter(AudioJackReader mReader, AudioManager mAudioManager,
                       int timeout, byte[] apdu, int cardType, Object locking){
        this.mReader = mReader;
        this.mAudioManager = mAudioManager;
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.apdu = apdu;
        this.cardType = cardType;
        this.locking = locking;
    }


    /**
     * Stops the polling thread
     */
    public void kill(){
        killMe = true;
    }


    /**
     * Updates the connection status of the reader (links to APDU response callback)
     */
    public void updateStatus(boolean status){
        readerConnected = status;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the APDU command for reading a card UID every second
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            /* Wait one second for stability */
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            while (!killMe) {
                synchronized(locking){

                    if(killMe){
                        continue;
                    }
                    /* If the reader is not connected, increment no. of iterations without response */
                    if(!readerConnected){
                        itersWithoutResponse++;
                    }
                    /* Else, reset the number of iterations without a response */
                    else{
                        itersWithoutResponse = 0;
                    }
                    /* Reset the connection state */
                    readerConnected = false;

                    if(itersWithoutResponse == 4) {
                        /* Communicate to the Cordova application that the reader is disconnected */
                        System.out.println("acr3x disconnected");
                        /* Kill this thread */
                        kill();
                    } else if(!mAudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()) {
                        System.out.println("acr3x not connected");
                        /* Kill this thread */
                        kill();
                    } else{
                        System.out.println("acr3x reading...");
                        /* Power on the PICC */
                        mReader.piccPowerOn(timeout, cardType);
                        /* Transmit the APDU */
                        mReader.piccTransmit(timeout, apdu);


                    }
                }
                /* Repeat every second */
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            /* Power off the PICC */
            mReader.piccPowerOff();
            /* Set the reader asleep */
            mReader.sleep();
            /* Stop the reader service */
            mReader.stop();

            synchronized(locking){
                locking.notifyAll();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO: add exception handling
        }
    }

}
```

listener interface:

```
public interface Acr3xNotifListener {

public void onUUIDAavailable(String uuid);
public void onFirmwareVersionAvailable(String firmwareVersion);
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While the link you have provided may answer the question, it is best to put the essential parts of your solution directly in your answer in case the page at the link disappears in the future.

Comment: I added by implementation.

Comment: saved my day. @smory tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

First you call the Reset command to activate the device.  As the device will fall asleep (after 4 seconds by default)* the trick is to keeping it alive.

You can achieve that by relaunching a new PowerOn command every time the previous PowerOn timedOut.  Something like that

```
void powerOn () {
if (!mReader.piccPowerOn(mPiccTimeout, mPiccCardType)) {
   powerOn();
} else {
   askNfcForItsId();
}
```

Don't forget to call powerOn after you read the nfc otherwise it will fall asleep after the 1st nfc card.

*the reset timeout can be set between 4 and 20 seconds