# Reading from NFC Card Using ACR35 NFC AudioJack Card Reader

Tags: android, nfc

I have recently started working with the ACR35 Audio Jack NFC card reader. I am developing an Android app to utilize this device but there isn't much to work with. An SDK was provided and a sketchy documentation. After some research on **StackOverflow**, i came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624394/how-to-use-acr35-nfc-reader-in-android/36334321#36334321)
but it wasn't so helpful. I am not able to find out if the device is on yet alone use it to read a card. I would really appreciate it if I got some assistance on this issue.